# Get distinct values with exclusion

Tags: mysql

I have a table (table1) storing these data:

```
location  category   other_columns
A         T1
A         T1
A         T2
A         T3

B         T1
B         T2
C         T1
C         T2
C         T3
C         T4
```

while there is another table (table2) to store the exclude list base on location, eg:

```
location  exclude_value
A   T1
B   T1
C   T4
```

Right now, I want to get distinct values for each location with its own exclusion. But I don't know how to draft the SQL. Could anyone provide a help? Thank you!

Comment: Show desired output for shown source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need in

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE (table1.location, table1.category) 
                        =
                         (table2.location, table2.category) );
```

?

Answer (score 0):

That's what `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is all about.

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2  USING(location, category)
    WHERE t2.id  IS NULL;
```